# Check if Dictionary<string,string> has continuous elements (DateTime)

Tags: c#, idictionary

I have the following `Dictionary<string,string>`:

```
bool hasContinuousDays = false;

var selectedDates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-21", DateTime.Now.ToString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-22", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-23", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-24", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString());
```

The above elements have continuous days (6,7,8,9) so `hasContinuousDays = true`.

```
var selectedDates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    selectedDates.Add("2014-06-21", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    selectedDates.Add("2014-06-24", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());
    selectedDates.Add("2014-06-25", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString());
    selectedDates.Add("2014-06-26", DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString());
```

The above elements have non continuous days so `hasContinuousDays = false`.

> How do I know if the Dictionary has continuous `DateTime`'s or not, **I should validate that using the Value** (not the Key).

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous days"? And why do you have a dictionary for strings where you obviously want to store Date(Time)s?

Comment: Get the Key collection from the dictionary, stuff it in a SortedSet (or any other sorted collection), and then scan over the list to find continuous date sequences. Done...

Comment: In both your examples the values have continuous dates.

Comment: I mean that the days are continuous, no gaps between them.

Comment: The dates in your example are continuous... The keys are not...  What are you looking for?

Comment: Which days? Since you say the second example doesn't have continuous days, but it should have it according to those rules.

Comment: This question is ludicrus

Comment: Sorry just updated, the second dictionary with non continuous days.

Comment: OK, and what about the example "have continuous days (6,7,8,9)", where does those numbers come from? Can you blame us for not understanding your question?

Comment: Sorry Just fixed the dictionaries :)

Comment: I would start by changing the dictionary to Dictionary<string, DateTime>, that would make the looping and date math more concise.

Comment: Ok, I can do that for sure :)

Comment: Key and value are the same, so why not use just a simple list/array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool hasContinuousDays = false;

var selectedDates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-21", DateTime.Now.ToString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-22", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-23", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-24", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString());

DateTime lastDay = DateTime.Parse(selectedDates.Values.First());
hasContinuousDays = selectedDates.Values.Skip(1).All(
        str=> {
                var day = DateTime.Parse(str); 
                var b = day == lastDay.AddDays(1); 
                lastDay = day; 
                return b;
            });

hasContinuousDays .Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a functional way of doing this. Given a `Dictionary<string,DateTime>` (which you should have), you can:

1. get a collection of the values
2. zip the collection with its tail, giving you a list of all consecutive pairs of dates
3. check that every pair is exactly one day apart

   ```
   var dates = selectedDates.Values;

   dates.OrderBy(d => d)
        .Zip(dates.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
        .All(pair => (pair.Item2 - pair.Item1).Days == 1);
   ```

Comment: I like that... The Zip() is a rather ingenius way of getting around needing an external variable (I tried with Aggregate() but got nowhere).

Comment: @JamesCurran Yeah, from my short experience with Scala, zipping a collection with its tail seems to be a fairly common technique in function languages.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
static bool IsContinuous(IDictionary<string,string> dates) {
  DateTime? lastDate = null;
  foreach (var date in dates
    .Values
    .Select(d => DateTime.Parse(d))
    .OrderBy(d => d)) {
    if (lastDate.HasValue && (date - lastDate.Value).TotalDays != 1.0) {
      return false;
    }
    lastDate = date;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Question is why do you serialize datetime to string (at least specify culture); the format of dictionary smells like xy problem.